# Find .xcscmblueprint file

Tags: ios, xcode8

I have been suffering from my project and the latest Xcode 8, it seems to be i can't find this file `.xcscmblueprint` that contains the source control details of my project.

There is some conflicts in that file and even if i deleted the git from my Xcode project it wont be fixed unless i fixed it from that file.

i am also using pods with this project and i tried a lot to find it but i couldn't and also in this location is not generated and not found :

> ProjectName > ProjectName.xcworkspace > xcshareddata >
>   ProjectName.xcscmblueprint

So how is it possible to generate or find this file ?

**Update:**

The main problem I'm facing with my git in the Xcode project is that the repository issue (scenario):

1- I have edited one class in the project.

2- i went to commit my changes in Xcode.

3- i get the following message :

[image]

4- In order for me to fix that i close Xcode completely and open it again and without changing anything.

5- commit and push the code successfully and Xcode doesn't complain about the repo.

- I tried to clean the Xcode project, remove the git from Xcode and re init a new git, its the same issue over and over and i just can't seem to fix it ones for all.

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: You have to fix the conflicts. No way out.

Comment: The problem is with this file and i used to find it but in Xcode 8 this file is no were to be found ! @shallowThought

Comment: You do not have to find it. As it has conflicts, your diff tool will know the path and open it automatically. Also the path should be visible in the conflict message. If I misunderstood and the file does not have conflicts but actually does not exist (not clear from your question), `git stash`your changes and checkout the previous commit.

Comment: @shallowThought can you check my update again ? thank you

Comment: I misunderstood than. Sorry. I do not use Xcode for version control, so I can not help any further.